# CSV to Plist Conversion IOS

Tags: ios, csv, plist

I need help turning my large spreadsheet into a plist. I want the key names to be Letters of the alphabet and the names to be values:

```
<plist version="1.0">
 <dict>
<key>A</key>
<array>
    <string>Amstel Light</string>
    <string>Anchor Porter</string>
    <string>Anchor Steam Beer</string>
    <string>Anheuser Busch Natural Light</string>
    <string>Asahi Draft Beer</string>
</array>
<key>B</key>
<array>
    <string>Ballentine India Pale Ale</string>
    <string>Ballentine Premium Lager</string>
    <string>Ballentine Private Stock Malt Liquor</string>
    <string>Ballentine XXX Ale </string>
    <string>Bass Bale Ale</string>
    <string>Beamish Irish Cream Stout</string>
    <string>Beamish Red Ale</string>
    <string>Beck Beer</string>
    <string>Big Barrell Australian Lager</string>
    <string>Black Horse Premium Draft Beer</string>
    <string>Blatz Beer</string>
    <string>Blatz Milwaukee 1851 Beer</string>
    <string>Boulder Porter</string>
    <string>Bud Light Beer</string>
    <string>Budweiser King of Beers</string>
    <string>Busch Beer</string>
```

I unfortunately had to enter these manually before, but my dataset is now enormous and contains about 1000 values. How can I automatically do this. I tried writing a Concatonate function in excel which gave me keys in the proper syntax but i still cannot copy and paste them easily due to formatting issues, basically It turns whole value into one line vs having it in four with the key, then array… The herokuapp method also does not create the keys in the way I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what does your CSV look like?